# hamachi does not work on beaglebone armhf the latest 130 version

Tags: beagleboneblack, hamachi

I tried the following codes:

```
sudo dpkg --force-architecture --force-depends -i logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.130-1_armhf.deb
apt-get -f install
```

It returned 
    /etc/init.d/logmein-hamachi: not found

but there is actually a binary file there

Answer (score 0):

sudo ln -s /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 /lib/ld-linux.so.3

Ref: http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7684048.html